# Sum all numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, sum

This is my code

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
var interval = 10000;
var refresh = function() {
$("#nodes").empty();
$.getJSON("https://tankionline.com/s/status.js",function(json){
  let sum = json.nodes.reduce((acc, obj)=>(val+obj.online+obj.inbattles), 0);
  console.log(sum);
  console.log("updated");
  var nodes = Object.keys(json.nodes).length;
   for (var i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
     var num = i + 1;
     var main = 'main.c' + num;
     $("#nodes").append(`
       <tr>
         <th scope="row">${num}</th>
         <td> ${json.nodes[main].online} </td>
         <td> ${json.nodes[main].inbattles} </td>
         <td> ${json.nodes[main].online - json.nodes[main].inbattles} </td>
       </tr>
       `)
    }
});
setTimeout(function() {
  refresh();
    },
  interval);
    }
  refresh();
});
```

In the json file are contained 20 servers, and in each server there is an online players value and an inbattles player value.
I want to obtain the sum of the online players and the sum of the inbattles players.
To archive that I tried to create an array outside the loop and inside the loop push the values to the array, and then do the sum.
But I don't think this is the best solution, so I'd like to know that is the best way to do it

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: The callback for [`getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) receives the data that is already parsed by `$.parseJSON`. Naming the var `json` is misleading because it tricks you into thinking it's JSON when it's not. Then you end up with things like `json.nodes` in your code which makes no sense. JSON is _never_ an object with properties that you would read directly like this. JSON can be parsed to get the value(s) out, but JSON is _always_ a String!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Updating...");
    $.getJSON("https://tankionline.com/s/status.js", function(data) {
      var totalOnline = Object.values(data.nodes).reduce((total, obj) => (total + obj.online), 0);
      var totalInBattles = Object.values(data.nodes).reduce((total, obj) => (total + obj.inbattles), 0);
      $("#online").val(totalOnline);
      $("#inBattles").val(totalInBattles);
    });
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Online:</label>
<input type="number" id="online" />

<label>In Battles:</label>
<input type="number" id="inBattles" />
```